# Utility for manually choosing audio outputs for Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, audio

I have a laptop with "Intel HD Audio" where the headphone detection mechanism is physically broken. The actual output itself works though, if it is selected manually, which is possible on Linux.

However, I am forced to (at least sometimes) run Windows 7 on it, where the driver offers no such option. I tried installing the SoundMAX driver for the actual ADC (AD1986A), and it worked, but didn't offer any more options than Microsoft's generic driver.

Are there any tools for Windows which can do something similar to Linux, i.e. manually choose which audio output to enable?

Comment: The default `Volume Mixer` allows you to do this.  If the port is unable to register if something is plugged then I know of no way to do what you want.  You can select which device you want to use using the `Volume Mixer`.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work in my case. Even when it registers that something is plugged in (it does when I push the plug to one side), the mixer only offers me the speakers and S/PDIF (which isn't even brought out). The headphones only work when I select the speaker output and hold the plug in the one awkward position where it is recognized.

I guess I'll just have to live without headphones in Windows.